# Starting a MVC Application in Visual Studio 2017 does not start mvcapplication but Owin does start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, owin

I've got a MVC 5 project which when I start debuggin (pressing F5) in Visual Studio the application starts but only the OWIN components are called. But the MvcApplication App_Start does not get called.

When I do the same on another computer the application starts.

Does anyone know what I can check?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the reason my application did not start was because of the following file "precompiledApp.config" in my root folder. I need to investigate why but it would seem that this caused the app to just stop working for some reason which I still need to find.

Hope this helps someone on the future. I've just spend 2 weeks trying to get my machine to work. Changed OS's, In place clear install and finally complete format just to find out once I've deleted the file my project works.